# Float two divs with child floated content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass

Is it possible without javascript to float two divs side by side when their child contents contain floated elements? I want to float my `.region-wrp` classes side by side.

The `.region-wrp` may have a number of children between 1 and 10 so this class cannot have a fixed width. So it's important that this class only takes up the width of its children.

```css
.col-md-8 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.region-wrp {
  border-top: 1px dashed red;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
}

.clear {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.item {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
      <div class="region-wrp">
        <div class="item">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eleifend mauris in erat facilisis, eleifend accumsan nisi eleifend. Pellentesque nec fermentum enim. Praesent bibendum ex condimentum, rhoncus diam non, gravida ex.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eleifend mauris in erat facilisis, eleifend accumsan nisi eleifend. Pellentesque nec fermentum enim. Praesent bibendum ex condimentum, rhoncus diam non, gravida ex.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="region-wrp">
      <div class="item">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eleifend mauris in erat facilisis, eleifend accumsan nisi eleifend. Pellentesque nec fermentum enim. Praesent bibendum ex condimentum, rhoncus diam non, gravida ex.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/nfc6458w/3/

Edit - I have this with no height, could be a better demo
https://jsfiddle.net/nfc6458w/14/

Comment: Of course that is "possible" ... _"I want to float my .region-wrp classes side by side"_ - then maybe you should place them on the same level first of all. Right now you have the first one inside the column, but the second one comes _after_ the column (talking about DOM here, not visual formatting) - not sure if that is what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

Of course You can. You just have to give them a width (like 50% each) as you did to the children (30%). Just don't use "width: auto" as if so, it will take 100% as a block element and they won't "float"

```
.region-wrp{
  border-top: 1px dashed red;
  float:left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%  ; 
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ebct39sw/

Comment: The region-wrp maybe contain 2 elements or it may contain 3 if it contains 3 then the width would be 100% divided into 1/3 + 1/3 +1/3. 

if it contains 2 items then it would 1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3 (from the 2nd region-wrp)

Therefore the region-wrp can never have a fix width it must only be the width of its children.

Comment: Then you need to use display flex insteed of floating or javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set margin-left: auto and margin-right: auto with a width of 50% since each will get half.

JSFiddle Example: https://jsfiddle.net/mikeferrari/37bdaper/

```
.region-wrp {
border-top: 1px dashed red;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
display: block;
width: 50%;
float: left;
}

.item {
float: left;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.col-md-8{
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.region-wrp{
  border-top: 1px dashed red;
  float:left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto; 
}
.clear{
    content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.item{
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <div class="region-wrp">
        <div class="item">
          <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eleifend mauris in erat facilisis, eleifend accumsan nisi eleifend. Pellentesque nec fermentum enim. Praesent bibendum ex condimentum, rhoncus diam non, gravida ex.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eleifend mauris in erat facilisis, eleifend accumsan nisi eleifend. Pellentesque nec fermentum enim. Praesent bibendum ex condimentum, rhoncus diam non, gravida ex.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <div class="region-wrp">
        <div class="item">
          <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eleifend mauris in erat facilisis, eleifend accumsan nisi eleifend. Pellentesque nec fermentum enim. Praesent bibendum ex condimentum, rhoncus diam non, gravida ex.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does this do? How does it answer the question? Dont' just blurt out code with no explanation.

Comment: Bootstrap offset class is added margin to the right, so if you need to place two div side by side then just add col-6 to both and apply 50% width to .itme class.